# Setting ${PWD} in PS1 variable does not work in Korn Shell

Tags: ksh, ps1

I have set the below as my PS1 variable in Solaris 5.10

```
PS1="\[${USER}@`uname -n` ${PWD}]\$ "
```

When I start my terminal session, it shows the correct directory(i.e my home directory) but when I change to some other directory it actually does not work. It still keeps on showing my home directory.

Any idea why this happens and how to rectify this ?

Answer (score 5):

Variables contained in strings enclosed in `"` get evaluated on the first encounter.

`$PS1` also gets evaluated every time before it's displayed.

You need to escape the `$` to postpone the evaluation of `$PWD`:

```
PS1="\[\${USER}@`uname -n` \${PWD}]\$ "
```

Comment: While this did work for me, I'm a little confused about the escaping, particularly about the first `[` and the last `$`. Could someone explain this for me?

Comment: shell prompt is interperted 2 times. 1 at creation of assignation and the second time at runtime.

Comment: Ok, thanks! And how about the last ']' which seems to be unescaped?

Comment: because only the opening start the interpretation process; so closing bracket wityhout opening have no special meaning